# Fast access and update integer matrix or array in Python

Tags: python, performance

I will need to create array of integer arrays like `[[0,1,2],[4,4,5,7]...[4,5]]`. The size of internal arrays changeable. Max number of internal arrays is `2^26`. So what do you recommend for the fastest way for updating this array. 
When I use `list=[[]] * 2^26` initialization is very fast but update is very slow. Instead I use

`list=[] , for i in range(2**26): list.append.([])` .

Now initialization is slow, update is fast. For example, for 16777216 internal array and 0.213827311993 avarage number of elements on each array for 2^26-element array it takes 1.67728900909 sec. It is good but I will work much bigger datas, hence I need the best way. Initialization time is not important.
Thank you.

Comment: Two points: 1. Don't call a list `list`, because it shadows the built-in name; and 2. Your first snippet doesn't do what you think it, try: `a = [[]] * 10; a[0].append('a'); a` and see what happens...

Comment: minor optimization: use `xrange` instead of `range`

Comment: Hmmm you are right list=[[]]*2^26 is completely different.Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I will try and write results here, xvatar.Thanks

Comment: list=[] , for i in range(2**26): list.append.([])  part is not important for me xvatar. This is only initialization. Update and access is much more important for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you ask is quite of a problem. Different data structures have different properties. In general, if you need quick access, do not use lists! They have linear access time, which means, the more you put in them, the longer it will take in average to access an element.

You could perhaps use numpy? That library has matrices that can be accessed quite fast, and can be reshaped on the fly. However, if you want to add or delete rows, it will might be a bit slow because it generally reallocates (thus copies) the entire data. So it is a trade off.

If you are gonna have so many internal arrays of different sizes, perhaps you could have a dictionary that contains the internal arrays. I think if it is indexed by integers it will be much faster than a list. Then, the internal arrays could be created with numpy.

Comment: why'd you say `list` has linear access time? according to this [page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) `list` has O(1) access time. It's implemented as an array

Comment: Exactly what I am doing is that, I have an integer list named nums includes about 300 numbers. Another list includes masks about 310000 elements in it. Then masking every number in nums array with all masks. Then indexing number in nums array by the result of masking. For example if '100' is an element in nums array. İf there is 2 elements '1' and '2' in masks list. result[1^100]=100 and result[2^100]=100.  List works a bit faster than dictionary. Here I am doing insertions after each operations. The nums array will include 3 million numbers so it will take much time.

Comment: I thınk list version is fast enough. Problem is xor'ing the numbers which costs much time.

Comment: Mmm interesting xvatar. I did not know that. Thanks for sharing it.